# Centralizar a lista no nav lateral

Tags: html, css

Comecei a aprender layout com CSS há pouco tempo. Estou com o certo problema de que a lista no div(**cinza**) lateral não está ficando no centro. 
É fácil ver o meu problema na hora de executar o programa.

Acredito que o 'ul' desloque o 'li' para a direita.

Agradeço quem me ajudar a colocar a lista no meio com a borda 2px encaixada.

```css
#geral {width: 100%;background: blue; border:2px solid;height: 5000px}

#teste {width: 100%; background: green;height: 100px; line-height: 100px; text-align: center; font-size: 80px}

#teste2 ul li{display: inline; padding: 10px}

#teste2 {width: 100%;height: 60px; line-height: 60px; text-align: center; font-size: 30%; background: yellow;position: relative;top: -80px}

#NavL {width: 20% ; background: grey; font-size: 20%; position: relative;top: -80px; height: 280px; line-height: 90px; float: left}

#NavL ul li {display: block;border:2px solid; text-align: center}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

 <head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name='Description' content="Formas">

 <title>Formas</title>
  
</head>

<body>

<div class=container id="geral">


<div id="teste">
 <p>TESTE</p>

<div id="teste2"> 
 <ul>
 <li>Início</li>
 <li>Contato</li>
 <li>Mais informações</li>
 </ul>
</div>

<div id="NavL">
 <nav>
  <ul>
<li>Mais caros</li>
<li>Mais baratos</li> <li>Infantil</li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem que tirar as margens e o padding da ul dentro da div `#NavL`:

```
#NavL ul{
  padding: 0; margin: 0;
}
```

```css
#geral {width: 100%;background: blue; border:2px solid;height: 5000px}

#teste {width: 100%; background: green;height: 100px; line-height: 100px; text-align: center; font-size: 80px}

#teste2 ul li{display: inline; padding: 10px}

#teste2 {width: 100%;height: 60px; line-height: 60px; text-align: center; font-size: 30%; background: yellow;position: relative;top: -80px}

#NavL {width: 20% ; background: grey; font-size: 20%; position: relative;top: -80px; height: 280px; line-height: 90px; float: left}

#NavL ul li {display: block;border:2px solid; text-align: center}

#NavL ul{
  padding: 0; margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

 <head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name='Description' content="Formas">

 <title>Formas</title>
  
</head>

<body>

<div class=container id="geral">


<div id="teste">
 <p>TESTE</p>

<div id="teste2"> 
 <ul>
 <li>Início</li>
 <li>Contato</li>
 <li>Mais informações</li>
 </ul>
</div>

<div id="NavL">
 <nav>
  <ul>
<li>Mais caros</li>
<li>Mais baratos</li> <li>Infantil</li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Esses margin e  padding que tirou são características do proprio ul, eles não tem relação com o div?

Comment: O UL tem margin e padding padrão. Dependendo de como você for usar uma lista não-ordenada (no caso, a UL), tem que resetar essas propriedades.